# How to send a State value to a component at the same level as a prop in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props, react-component

I have a structure of components like this:

- SeleccionadorEmpresa
- Chart
- Nombres

All this componenets are inside the main App component. I want to send a state value from SeleccionadorEmpresa to Nombres, but Nombres is not a child element of SeleccionadorEmpresa, they are components at the same level. How can I send the state value as a props from SeleccionadorEmpresa to Nombres?

Comment: You should look into using Redux for global state management.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should lift the state up to the parent component.
Then the associated state values and setters can be passed down as props.

https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

function App(props) {
  const [nombres, setNombres] = useState("nombres");
  return (
    <SeleccionadorEmpresa nombres={nombres} setNombres={setNombres} />
    <Nombres nombres={nombres} />
  );
}

function SeleccionadorEmpresa({ nombres, setNombres }) {
  return (
    <button onClick={() => setNombres(`${nombres} nombres!`)}>
      click
    </button>
  );
}

function Nombres({ nombres }) {
  return (
    <pre>nombres: {nombres}</pre>
  );
}
```

Comment: And for example if Nombre was a Class Based Component how can I call nombres variable?

Answer (score 3):

You should control both state on the parent class and then the parent will send the values to the child, in this case a

Comment: For example, send the values to the App component that is containing the other components, and after that sending the values to Nombres?

Comment: Kinda,  in your case the state should stay on the App and you pass it as a prop to the children, if you want to modify from the children you can pass a function as a props that do so.

Comment: Can I modify the state of App from a children component?

Comment: Yes, you should create a function on the App component e.g. `handleStateX(){
this.setState(x: !this.state.x)}` and then pass this function to you child as a prop

Answer (score 1):

React is all about data flowing down the component's tree, so that means horizontal data flow is anti pattern. If you need to share state between two or more siblings the solution would be [lift your state up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html). What does that means? You should transfer your state to a parent component that wrap all the siblings, now from your wrapper just distribute your data down via props.